# Thinking Async - not an easy task Node.js + Express.JS

Tags: node.js, express, node-async

The following question is asked in order to better understand from your answers how to think "Async" when developing on Node.js

I have the following code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    ... //Definition of rules and paramsObj

    //Validation that returns a promise 
    Indicative.validate(rules,paramsObj)

    .then(function(success){
        //we passed the validation. start processing the request

        //ProcessRequest has async calls but when all async functions are over, it sets paramObj.someVal with a calculated value.
        processRequest(paramsObj,next);

        //My problem is here. at this point paramsObj.someVal is not set yet. and therefore the response to the user will be incorrect.
        res.send(paramsObj.someVal);
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
        next(err);
    }).done();
}
```

I wish to understand how to better think "async" while i need to wait with the response to the user until all async functions are over.

My question is how to execute `res.send(paramObj.someVal)` only after the `paramObj.someVal` is set by some async methods in `processRequest(paramsObj,next);`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  It is not clear what question you're asking.  There is no generic answer to how to "better think async".

Comment: //My problem is here. at this point paramsObj.someVal is not yet set. and therefore the response to the user will be incorrect.
        `res.send(paramsObj.someVal);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to wait on the result of `processRequest` for `paramsObj.someVal` to be set then ultimately you need to handle that callback

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    ... //Definition of rules and paramsObj

    //Validation that returns a promise 
    Indicative.validate(rules,paramsObj)

    .then(function(success){
        //we passed the validation. start processing the request

        //ProcessRequest has async calls but when all async functions are over, it sets paramObj.someVal with a calculated value.
        processRequest(paramsObj, function(err) {
            if (!err && !paramsObj.someVal) {
                // raise a custom error if the value is not set
                err = new Error('Value not set');
            }
            if (err) {
                next(err);
            } else {
                res.send(paramsObj.someVal);
            }
        });

    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
        next(err);
    }).done();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the second argument to `processRequest()` is a completion callback, you can pass your own function for that callback and do your `res.send()` in that custom callback like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    ... //Definition of rules and paramsObj

    //Validation that returns a promise 
    Indicative.validate(rules,paramsObj)

    .then(function(success){
        //we passed the validation. start processing the request

        //ProcessRequest has async calls but when all async functions are over, it sets paramObj.someVal with a calculated value.
        processRequest(paramsObj,function() {
            res.send(paramsObj.someVal);
        });

    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
        next(err);
    }).done();
}
```

Since you do `res.send(...)`, I assume you don't want to actually call `next()` in that code path.

Comment: How the callback function gets invoked? Should i call it from `processRequest` at the point of time where `paramsObj.someVal` is set?

Comment: @TBE - Yes, the callback should be called from inside `processRequest()` when it is done with everything and `paramsObj.someVal` is now set.

Comment: so its kinda cheating as we force sync flow in an async environment.

Comment: @tbe - Not cheating.  Just how you write async code.